# Mount partitions for only one user

Tags: mount, ntfs

Like the title says, is there a way to mount a partition (on boot or on login) for only one user, so that other users can't access the files but only me?

I searched for some fstab parameters but i found nothing I that would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what file system you are using for the mounted partition you can use the mount options `gid=XX,uid=XXXX` (group-id and user-id) - see `man mount` for more information on what file systems support them. Users are listed in `/etc/passwd` while groups are listed in `/etc/group`. For your user, you can use the `id` command. You can then set the umask-like options to set file permissions.

Here is an example of using them in `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=<xxxxx> /media/win ntfs rw,auto,nls=utf8,umask=077,gid=46,uid=1000    0   0
```

And here the same as a mount command:

```
sudo mount -U <xxxx> -t ntfs -o rw,auto,nls=utf8,umask=077,gid=46,uuid=100 /media/win
```

File systems that don't have `gid` and `uid` as an option, usually can have their rights set in the normal way after you mounted the partitionm i.e. recursively for all files with `chmod go-rwx -R /media/mountpoint` (or what ever other mountpoint suits your fancy).

Comment: Works but has a little constraint: If the other user has root rights (is in sudoers file), he can remount the partition manually to access it himself.

Comment: Of course. Thank you so much for that comment; also you can only do this, if the disk is not broken... ;D

Comment: I was trying to provide helpful information for @a2r considering he may be a beginner to linux who doesn't think of this. There is no need to be sarcastic about it.

Comment: Chill out guys ;) 
I'm not a beginner, but also I'm not that skilled. I knew how to add partitions to the fstab (and that sudoers can do everything^^)
The only thing i didn't know was the user and group management.
I assume that 
"plugdev:x:46:arthur" means, that i am the only one in that group? And that this group is for plugin in devices?